# Insert into MYSQL based on If else statement

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys I have this simple MYSQL statement which I can't seem to insert into database properly..

```
if($item_cat == "Hardware") {
    $item_filter = "2";
    $item_filter = trim($_POST['item_filter']);
    $item_filter = strip_tags($item_filter);
    $item_filter = htmlspecialchars($item_filter);
 } elseif($item_cat == "Software") {
    $item_filter = "3";
    $item_filter = trim($_POST['item_filter']);
    $item_filter = strip_tags($item_filter);
    $item_filter = htmlspecialchars($item_filter);
 }

 $query = "INSERT INTO items(item_cat , item_filter) VALUES('$item_cat','$item_filter')";
```

The concept I want to achieve is based on the user's selection of a select input (hardware or software) the item_filter is added based on this selection. When I try and run this code it tells me `item_filter is undefined.`

Any help or another approach to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If needed I can also add the HTML code

Comment: $_POST['item_filter'] is undefined

Comment: Sorry, it is kinda confusing.

Comment: What's confusing? I have 2 variables one inside the form element (the body of the page called item_cat) the other is right before the select statement. When a user selects an option from the item_cat it will read it from the if else statement and put it in the database.

Comment: confusing is why you use  $item_filter = "3"; or  $item_filter = "2"; i don't find any use of them.

Comment: It's because I'm using a Jquery filteration library called Filtrizer which only accepts categories in numbers rather than strings, that's why I added this item_filter.

Comment: thats not what i mean. you assign value 2/3 into $item_filter variable and immediately in next line you assign another value into it. then why assign first time?

Comment: That was the mistake I did and was fixed in the answer.. I put in 
`$item_filter= trim($_POST['item_filter']);
$item_filter= strip_tags($item_filter);
$item_filter= htmlspecialchars($item_filter);` because I got used to do it in all my codes.. so it was a habit.. But now it's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so much code to filter the variable.Use a function and call it when needed.

First you are saying $item_filter=2 or 3 then you are assigning the variable like this 
`$item_filter = trim($_POST['item_filter']);`
may be you don't have item_filter named input.

```
function filter($data){
  $data =   trim($data);
  $data = strip_tags($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

$item_cat=filter($_POST['item_cat']);

if($item_cat == "Hardware")
 {
  $item_filter = "2";
 }
 else if($item_cat == "Software")
 {
  $item_filter = "3";
 }

$query = "INSERT INTO items(item_cat , item_filter) VALUES('$item_cat','$item_filter')";
```

Comment: Thank you sir.. but can you explain why the codes below it were wrong?

Comment: Would be also helpful to explain why you would use == to compare strings instead of strcmp.

Answer (score 0):

Either `$_POST['item_filter']` is undefined or your category isn't "Hardware" or "Software". Try `var_dump($item_cat)` before your code sample and make sure you're actually passing one of the `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO items(item_cat , item_filter) 
VALUES
(
(CASE item_filter WHEN 'Hardware' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
$item_filter = "";
if(strtolower($item_cat) == "hardware")
 {
  $item_filter = "2";
  $item_filter = trim($_POST['item_filter']);
  $item_filter = strip_tags($item_filter);
  $item_filter = htmlspecialchars($item_filter);
 }
 elseif(strtolower($item_cat) == "software")
 {
  $item_filter = "3";
  $item_filter = trim($_POST['item_filter']);
  $item_filter = strip_tags($item_filter);
  $item_filter = htmlspecialchars($item_filter);

 }
```